# How do I disable a single option in an OptionMenu?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

If the user selects one option from the `OptionMenu` list then that option should get disabled.

Example: if the user selects "a" then option "a" should get disabled and the user can then only select b or c. I tried the code below but it returns the error as shown. I don't want a `menubutton`. `OptionMenu` will serve my purpose but not a `menubutton`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class Disable_state(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        va = StringVar()
        NAMES = { 'a' : 0, 'b' : 1, 'c' : 2 }
        op = list(NAMES.keys())
        self.menu = OptionMenu(self.parent, va, *op,command = lambda op: self.disable_option(op))
        self.menu.grid(column=0, row=0)
    def disable_option(self,op):
        self.menu.config(op, state = "disabled")


if __name__ =="__main__":
    root= Tk()
    o = Disable_state(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

The error is

```
self.menu.config(op, state = "disabled")
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1319, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1303, in _configure
    cnf = _cnfmerge((cnf, kw))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 105, in _cnfmerge
    cnf.update(c)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is  required
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to be possible to access a subwidget `menu`, and using the `entryconfigure` method an entry can be disabled

```
self.menu['menu'].entryconfigure(op, state = "disabled")
```