# How to disable an option within an option menu in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

The issue I am having is that i have an option menu, and I am appending a list with the option that is selected, but if the option is selected twice, then it is duplicated in the list.

I am thinking that disabling the current selected option will be the easiest way around this, however while I am stuck on this part due to still being new to the syntax of tkinter, I am working on seeing if I can remove the duplicate item in the list if it is selected again.

Below is a list that I made, if anyone can show me how I can make the current selected option disabled, I would be very grateful. Alternatively, if there is already a detailed article showing a solution, a link to that would also be great!

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

designOptions1 = [" ", "Design 1", "Design 2"]
designMenu1 = OptionMenu(root, *designOptions1)
designMenu1.config(width = 10, height = 3)

designMenu1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Check [How do I disable a single option in an OptionMenu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36414738/how-do-i-disable-a-single-option-in-an-optionmenu?msclkid=93b90856b44011ec80e53bd60051bf26)

Comment: Yep, I've been reading through it trying to see how I can implement the answer into my code, however my attempts have not been successful

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
choice = om1str.get()
designMenu1['menu'].entryconfigure(choice, state = 'disabled')
```

this would work.
PS: Had the same problem today